# the drag and drop operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I know how to implement the drag and drop effect in JavaScript,but I found that in some site,the speed of the drag and drop operation will cause different result.

Take the Google map for example,the map view is draggable ,when you drag the map slowly,the map will move with your mouse ,however if you drag the map very fast and then drop the mouse,the map will keep moving (a limited distance),it seems that it has a buffer distance.

I wonder how to make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no vanilla effect for that, unfortunately.

You will have to count various parameters such as distance, direction and time that it took to  complete the drag.

Then depending on the results you can compute a bezier curve and extend the animation so that it seems seamless and smooth.

Here's an example...
http://jsfiddle.net/an44z/

It works, if maybe not that well (written hastily for an old project, but it might give you a good idea of what is happening - should be happening).

EDIT: Alternatively you can study this mooTools example since it is pretty much exactly  what you're after.
http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Drag.Scroll

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for some sort of "drag velocity". I spent some time this morning [putting this mouse-to-throw example together](http://jsfiddle.net/52tX7/1/) for you so I hope it helps (I had some fun making it too). The *principle * is the same for what you're wanting to do and is something you can have a lot of fun with.

Brunt of Javascript used:

```
// this is the easing I used in my "throwing" animation
// I use this to average out some of the arrays (distance & angle)
$.easing.easeOutCirc = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
}

// stores the last drag spot, useful for calculating distances between points
var drag_last_spot;
// stores distances for use with calculating animation distance
var drag_distances;
// stores rads for use with calculating throw angle
var drag_rads;
// keeps the offset of the initial click to know where the mouse "went down" on the box
var drag_offset;
// keeps track of the "current target" since mouseUp and MouseMove are document level
var drag_target;
// keeps track of how long you held your mouse down on the box (to determine animation length)
var drag_time;

// taken via Google from http://jsfromhell.com/array/average
average = function(a){
    var r = {mean: 0, variance: 0, deviation: 0}, t = a.length;
    for(var m, s = 0, l = t; l--; s += a[l]);
    for(m = r.mean = s / t, l = t, s = 0; l--; s += Math.pow(a[l] - m, 2));
    return r.deviation = Math.sqrt(r.variance = s / t), r;
}
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // offset and last_spot are the same for the first move iteration
    drag_time = (new Date).getTime();
    drag_offset = drag_last_spot = {
        x: event.offsetX,
        y: event.offsetY
    };

    // initialize or reset the distances and angle arrays
    drag_distances = [];
    drag_rads = [];

    // because there are multiple boxes, we need to keep track of the target since our events are document level
    drag_target = $(this);

    $(document).bind("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    $(document).bind("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    // use pathagorean theorem for distance between two points (yay geometry!)
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(drag_last_spot.x - event.clientX, 2) + Math.pow(drag_last_spot.y - event.clientY, 2));

    // push all the distances to this array for later use
    drag_distances.push(dist);

    // push all radians to this array for later use
    var cur_rad = Math.atan2(event.clientY - drag_last_spot.y, event.clientX - drag_last_spot.x);
    drag_rads.push(cur_rad);

    // we need to know the last drag spot so we can calc the distance of the points during the next onMouseMove
    drag_last_spot = {
        x: event.clientX,
        y: event.clientY
    };

    drag_target.css({left:event.clientX - drag_offset.x, top:event.clientY - drag_offset.y});
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    /* FYI wherever you see .slice(-N) you can change N to any number. I recommend a small number as a short drag will only have 5 or 10 items. A big number will average more of your "throw", but a small number is seemingly safer.*/

    // this is the total duration of how long you dragged for
    var duration = ((new Date).getTime() - drag_time);

    // this is the distance of your drag (I times by three for a better animated effect)
    var dist = average(drag_distances.slice(-3)).mean * 3;

    // these help determine the direction of your throw (figures out the angle)
    var rad = average(drag_rads.slice(-3)).mean - Math.PI / 2;
    var to_left = event.clientX + Math.sin(rad) * -dist - drag_offset.x;
    var to_top = event.clientY + Math.cos(rad) * dist - drag_offset.y;

    // now to animation your throw!
    drag_target.animate({left:to_left, top:to_top}, duration * 2, "easeOutCirc");

    $(document).unbind("mousemove");
    $(document).unbind("mouseup");
}
```

This example is just the tip of the iceberg so I say mess around with the script to learn how it works as you'll likely come up with new cool ways to do things. **Good luck!**